# how to showed that X is Hausdorff and compact

Tags: general-topology

Consider the equivalence relation $‘∼’ $on R × [0, 1] defined by
$(x, t) ∼ (x + 1, t), x ∈ R$ and$ t ∈ [0, 1].$
Let $X =(R × [0, 1])/ ∼$ be the quotient space.

Prove that X is
Hausdorff and compact.

i was thinking that ,If the quotient map is open, then $X/ \sim$ is a Hausdorff space if and only if $\sim$ is a closed subset of the product space $[0,1]\times X$.

as im very weak in topology  and im  newly learning topology

pliz help me

Comment: It seems X is homeomorphic to [0,1)×[0,1]  which is Hausdorff and not compact.

Comment: @WilliamElliot $X$ is homeomorphic to $S^1\times[0,1]$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $f:\mathbb R\times[0,1]\to S^1\times[0,1]$ be prescribed by:$$\langle x,t\rangle\mapsto\langle\langle\cos2\pi x,\sin2\pi x\rangle,t\rangle$$

Then $f$ is continuous and surjective.

Further it can be shown that $f$ is a closed map, hence $f$ is a quotient map.

If $q:\mathbb R\times[0,1]\to X$ denotes the quotient map then it can be shown that $f$ and $q$ respect each other in the sense that $f(x,t)=f(y,s)\iff q(x,t)=q(y,s)$.

Based on these facts it can be shown that $X$ and $S^1\times[0,1]$ are homeomorphic, so it remains to prove now that $S^1\times[0,1]$ is compact and Hausdorff.

Comment: thanks  alots .@drhab as i was  thinking  about   how $\mathbb R\times[0,1]homeomorphism  S^1\times[0,1]$???  as R  is connected but not compact

Comment: ok i got its @drhab